# Doubly Generic Types in C#

Tags: c#, generics

I'm new to C#, so sorry for the syntax question, but I can't find the answer anywhere. I'm trying to make a type with the following type-architecture

```
public abstract class MyAbstractType {...}
public class MyFirstType : MyAbstractType {...}
public class MySecondType : MyAbstractType {...}

public abstract class AbstractHeap<T> {...}
public class MyFirstHeap : AbstractHeap<MyFirstType> {...}
public class MySecondHeap : AbstractHeap<MySecondHeap> {...}

public class MetaHeap<T1,T2> : AbstractHeap<T1> where T2 : AbstractHeap<T3> where T3 : MyAbstractType {...}
```

The last definition is the one giving me the problems. Is it just a syntax problem that I don't realize, or is this kind of structure not allowed in C#?

Comment: Care to actually show what "the problems" this line gives (which seem to be perfectly syntactically correct)?

Comment: you'd need T3 specified in `class MetaHeap<T1,T2,T3>` and you can probably get away with fewer generic parameters. 
What is the actual problem here?

Comment: Thanks! Works if I specify the T3.

Comment: I'm trying to make a heap of heaps ordered on T1, where the sub-heaps are ordered on T3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're almost there. There are three type parameters in this declaration, but you put only two in the `MetaHeap<>` braces and forgot `T3`.

```cs
public class MetaHeap<T1,T2,T3> : AbstractHeap<T1> 
    where T2 : AbstractHeap<T3> 
    where T3 : MyAbstractType {...}
```

Comment: ah.. whoops. Thanks!